Can I swap the power cables for the motherboard at the PSU socker?
The last time I built a PC was when the Pentium was the new hotness. However, I have decided to build my own instead of buying a new PC.
I'm a bit confused with this modular power supply cable situation. The power supply (Season Focus SGX-750) came with a motherboard cable. However, the 18 pin and 10 pin cables appear to go only one way due to the way they are connected together, but it doesn't line up with the power supply itself. They are swapped:


I could pull the cables apart and try to reverse them, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do in this situation. I'm also very confused as to why the cables included with the PSU would be configured this way.
Do I need to buy new cables for the motherboard?

I'm not familiar with that particular modular PSU, but this is really weird. It doesn't look like there is enough leeway in the cable-loom to swap the connectors. At least not without separating the fused cables further than that they already are. Normally you would get 2 (or 3) motherboard cables (as the connector layout on motherboard side can have some variations), but the PSU side for all is the same and should "just fit". Looks like you got the wrong cable in the box. I would recommend to contact their customer support.

Looking at the images on the Seasonic website https://seasonic.com/focus-sgx-2021#gallery this does just appear to be the way the cables and connectors are ordered. It seems that a new set of cables might not fix your issue. Reddit seems to suggest that an MSI MPG A1000G has a similar problem and the fix is indeed to split the cable bundles, but from what I can find the 10 and 18 way connectors are the other way around. Same at https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/7ttfb0 I'd just split the cable bundles personally.

Goes without saying modular power supply cables are not all created the same and are NOT compatible with one another
